# What is the best option for a primary key in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, primary-key, database-schema

I have a small database where I have two tables: Items and Images.  In Items, I have a column named `ItemSys` which is a `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`.  My current Images table creation script looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.Images (
    ImageSys SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ItemSys INT NOT NULL,
    ImageSeq INT NOT NULL,
    ImageLocation VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    UNIQUE (ItemSys, ImageSeq)
);
```

Other than giving the table a column that will always have a unique `INT` value, `ImageSys` is not used.  To retrieve all images for an item, I will be using the `ItemSys` in a `JOIN`.  Is my current definition the best way to go, or should I remove `ImageSys` and define the primary key over `ItemSys` and `ImageSeq`?

Again, I will only be joining over `ItemSys` (not `ImageSeq`), but `ImageSeq` will be unique per `ItemSys` (and will be used for sorting).

Comment: If your items table has a foreign key reference to images, you will need two fields instead of one.  So you'll be robbing Peter to pay Paul.

Comment: If ItemSys is unique then just declare this to be the primary key. Unnecessary composite primary keys take a toll on performance, as well as an unnecessary column ImageSys.

Comment: ItemSys is only unique to the Items table.  There can be many images to one item, so in the Images table, ItemSys is not unique, but the combo of ItemSys and ImageSeq is unique.

Comment: Modifying the primary key value of an existing record is a bad idea (updates need to cascade to FKs, triggers are much harder to write, auditing becomes nearly impossible, and ORMs don't cope well at all with a record's identity changing). `ImageSeq` sounds like something you might want to update. Stick with the generated key.

Comment: I haven't applied my schema script to my production DB yet.  I can make any change to the script I need to without repercussion.